# Custom Keyboard iOS - Orientation change - Autolayout constraints applied not smoothly

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard and also it supports landscape and portrait orientation.My issue is when i change the orientation keyboard view changes its height and width which happens not like native keyboard.video is added below.I want keyboard to adjust is size like native keyboard.

I am updating keyboard height in viewWillTransitionTSize added below

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

[self updateKeyboardHeight];
}

-(void)updateKeyboardHeight{
if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0)
    return;
[self.inputView removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];

CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
CGFloat realScreenHeight = MAX(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == realScreenHeight)
{
    //Landscape
    self.isLandscape = YES;
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.landscapeHeight;
    _currentOrientation = LKeyboardButtonLandscape;
    [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];

}
else
{
    //Portrait
    self.isLandscape = NO;
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.portraitHeight;
     _currentOrientation = LKeyboardButtonPortrait;
    [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: No video is available.

Comment: @Priyal ...Sorry Just now added

Comment: You should try on device too instead of just simulator.

Comment: @Rikh..Thanks for your reply...In Device also I am getting the same.